# Alternatives to "to be a(n, sic) own +noun"

Tags: phrase-requests

In a sister site there is this question.

[image]

Complete question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/352727/is-actor-a-own-class

The person is asking whether or not the "actor" (little stick man, in this case "customer" that interacts with the system) in the diagram can or should be considered a class (a software component) in the design or a software product.

But the phrasing looks a little odd to me.

I've considering editing the answer to improve the title but the following alternatives that have come to my mind don't convey the meaning exactly as they somehow have the additional meaning of "alone, separated, without help":

- Is the actor a class on its own?
- Is the actor a class in its own right?
- Is the actor a class in and of itself?

In the other hand the following sounds weirdly informal to me:

- Is the actor its own class?

Questions

- What would be a phrasing that would convey the perceived intention of the question being asked?
- Ultimately, is the original phrase in the title proper english?

Comment: shouldn't "a own" be "an own" to begin with? and as a programmer (but not a native english speaker), I would say "standalone class" - "normally, an actor is not a standalone class".

Comment: @DavidHaim Standalone falls into the category of alternatives that convey the undesired meaning of "alone, not needing any collaborator or help", along with "on its own", etc

Comment: @DavidHaim He means a class as opossite to just a actual person interacting with the system.

Comment: The rest of the referenced question might be useful to determine what they meant by "own class". Can you add a link to it in your question?

Comment: @Lawrence Sure, I added the URL.

Comment: I like "in its own right."

Comment: Also: "Is the actor, by itself, a class?" ... Intead of "in and on itself" we usually say "in and of itself".

Comment: First of all, standalone is a neutral word for independent, with no undesired connotations. Second, 'a own' is a typo each time it is used. Your own choices are good. The actor is a class of one.